# Change Key Name in nested JSON mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I want to change the Key Name of the first and second level of the JSON in mysql.
For this I have a table called `content` and a column called `attribs` and the data stored is as follows:

```
{"author": "Nika", "link_url": "", "gallery": "{\"gallery_images\":[\"images/2017/09/30/blog_011.jpg\",\"images/2017/09/30/blog_010.jpg\",\"images/2017/09/30/blog_009.jpg\"]}", "show_urls": ""}
```

I would like it to be as follows:

```
{"post_author": "Nika", "link_url": "", "gallery": "{\"post_gallery_images\":[\"images/2017/09/30/blog_011.jpg\",\"images/2017/09/30/blog_010.jpg\",\"images/2017/09/30/blog_009.jpg\"]}", "show_urls": ""}
```

In sumary I want change `author` by `post_author` and `gallery_images` by `post_gallery_images`

UPDATE: I tried following; but it only change first level. I tried other methos from Mysql Docs and Answers here in Stackoverflow but not wor for second level.

```
UPDATE adneit_content SET attribs = REPLACE(attribs, '"author":', '"post_author":');
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's no direct way to replace a key. You have to get the old value of the key, set the new key to that value, and delete the old key. Hardly anything is easy with MySQL's JSON functions, and this will be especially difficult.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for four comment I Updated with more info, Regards

Comment: You need to match the backslashes in the nested JSON. Why do you have nested JSON in the first place, can you fix that so it's just a nested object?

Comment: @Barmar The database has more than 1000 identical records, so the idea was to change the names of the keys to recover them with the new system that continues to store nested like this. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the nested keys, you need to match the backslashes as well.

```
UPDATE adneit_content 
SET attribs = REPLACE(
                REPLACE(attribs, '"author":', '"post_author":'), 
                '\\"gallery_images\\":', '\\"post_gallery_images\\":')
```

Comment: I don't know how correct it is but this one also worked for me for second level, maybe it will help someone `UPDATE adneit_content SET attribs = REPLACE(attribs, 'gallery_images', 'post_gallery_images');`

Comment: Leaving out the quotes will work only if those strings don't appear anywhere other than the property names. So it's not as safe.